# How to store string containing different language (like Chinese, hindi etc) in MySql 5.0

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog

I am making use of mysql 5.0. Is there a way to store a string containing different language other than english? I tried to store the language Kannada but its storing it as "?????". i even tried changing encoding to utf-8, dosent work. (sqlyog)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the following query to change the column as utf8:

```
  ALTER TABLE TableName MODIFY ColumnName VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET UTF8;
```

Answer (score 0):

change the field collation to :-

```
utf8_general_ci
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should execute this command..

> ALTER TABLE  CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;